# Angular Js performance and load time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive, performance-testing

I am working on Angular Js web app using Laravel 5.2 as API and I have a big issue in the performance specially in the load time of the home page.

I have a request that get 5 sections from database, each section has one or tow items and each item has many comments. I loop through sections then items then comments to render it via nested `ng-repeat` directive.

I also have a list of filters and another of friends each has its own request and `ng-repeat` to render it as well.

Is this considerable as huge data to use over Angular JS, How I can enhance the performance of it?

I also have about 20 modules in the dependencies of the main module, Is there a better way to load this module only when I need them?

Notes:

1. Angular Js version 1.5.1
2. Angular Js and jQuery loaded via CDN
3. all other js files are concatenated by GULP.js in one file and it about 66000 lines of code
4. there is 25 module in the dependencies array of the main module
5. the time of load is about 25-35 seconds

here is code of my home page section that cause the issue:

```html
        <div ng-class="{'col-sm-6':currentUser,'col-sm-9':!currenUser}" fc-loading="getCoupons" class="allCoupons lbm">
            <section class="fc-section text-center fc-direction" ng-init='current="all"'>
                <button type="button" class='btn  btnp btnm0 srm' ng-class='{"btnr":current=="all"}' ng-click='updateCoupons();current="all"' name="button">كل الكوبونات</button>
                <button type="button" class='btn btnp  btnm0' ng-class='{"btnr":current=="my"}' ng-click='updateCoupons("user");current="my"' name="button">الكوبونات المخصصة لك </button>
            </section>

                <div  ng-repeat='(key,section) in coupon_sections' class="{{key}} fc-programs">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <h3 class="pull-left">{{::section.type}}</h3>
                            <ul ng-init="active = 'newset'" class="pull-right">
                                <li ng-click="sortCoupons(1,key); active='newset'" ng-class="{active:active == 'newset'}"><span>{{::'sort_by.newest'| translate}}</span></li>
                                <li ng-click="sortCoupons(2,key); active='oldset'" ng-class="{active:active == 'oldset'}"><span>{{::'sort_by.oldest'| translate}}</span></li>
                                <li ng-click="sortCoupons(3,key); active='popular'" ng-class="{active:active == 'popular'}"><span>{{::'sort_by.popular'| translate}} </span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-section">
                      <p>
                        {{::section.description}}
                      </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="lucky_hour centerContainer" ng-if='key =="luckyHour"' ng-init='getTimeRemaining("December 31 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0200")'>
                      <div class="centerContent">
                        <ul>
                          <li class="hh" ng-repeat='hour in hours track by $index'>{{hour}}</li>
                          <li class="dots">:</li>
                          <li class="mm" ng-repeat="minute in minutes track by $index">{{minute}}</li>
                          <li class="dots">:</li>
                          <li class="ss" ng-repeat="second in seconds track by $index">{{second}}</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <section class="fc-section text-center" ng-if="!section.coupons.length ">
                        <p class="title">{{::'no_coupons'| translate}}</p>
                    </section>
                    <div ng-repeat="coupon in section.coupons">
                        <fc-coupon ng-init='showCarousel();'></fc-coupon>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center" ng-if="section.coupons.length ">
                        <button  class="btnloadmore icon-plus-circled btni lbm" ng-click="loadMore(key)">{{::'load_more'| translate}}</button>
                    </div>


                </div>


        </div>
```

here is the fc-coupon template

```html
<div class="fc-coupon lbm" id='{{coupon.coupon_data.slug}}'>

    <div class="header bb">
      <div class="rippon">
{{::coupon.coupon_data.type}}      </div>
        <img  style="background-image: url('{{::absolute_url+'images/brands/100x100/'+ coupon.brand_data.logo }}')" />

        <h3>{{::coupon.brand_data.name}}</h3>
        <fc-stars   rating="{{::coupon.coupon_data.rate}}" ></fc-stars>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <!-- <label>{{::'available_for'| translate}}</label> -->
            <div class="fc-badge sPadges" ng-repeat="customer in ::coupon.coupon_data.users_type">
                <img uib-tooltip="{{:: 'available_for' | translate}} {{::customer.name.name}}" ng-src="{{::absolute_url}}/images/customer-types/50x50/{{customer.image}}">
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="sp" ng-if='key !="challenges"'>
      <h4>{{::coupon.coupon_data.title}}</h4>
      <p hm-read-more
         hm-text="{{:: coupon.coupon_data.description }}"
         hm-limit="100"
         hm-more-text="{{::'read_more'|translate}}"
         hm-less-text="{{::'read_less'|translate}}"
         hm-dots-class="dots"
         hm-link-class="links" class="sbm mtp "></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sp mtp" ng-if='key =="challenges"'>
      <p>
        <i class="fc-red icon-award"></i> <span class="fc-purple srm">التحدي </span>
        {{::coupon.coupon_data.challenges.name}}
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fc-red icon-gift"></i> <span class="fc-purple srm">الجائزة </span>
          <span>{{::coupon.coupon_data.type}}</span>
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="couponImage">
        <div class="fc-overlay centerContainer">
            <div class="centerContent">
                <i ng-if="coupon.coupon_data.in_wallet" class="icon-heart"></i>
                <i ng-if="!coupon.coupon_data.in_wallet" ng-click="addToMyCoupons(coupon.coupon_data)" class="icon-heart-empty"></i>

                <label>{{::coupon.coupon_data.no_of_users_in_wallet }}</label>

            </div>
            <div class="couponFooter">
                <a href="{{::absolute_url}}/{{lang}}/coupon/{{coupon.slug}}">{{::'details'| translate}}</a>
                <ul class="socials">
                    <li><span ng-click="shareCoupon(coupon.coupon_data.slug,'facebook')" spantarget="_blank" class="icon-facebook"></span> </li>
                    <li><span ng-click="shareCoupon(coupon.coupon_data.slug,'twitter')" class="icon-twitter"></span> </li>
                    <li><span ng-click="shareCoupon(coupon.coupon_data.slug,'gplus')" class="icon-gplus"></span> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img ng-src="{{::absolute_url}}/images/coupons/747x390/{{coupon.coupon_data.image}}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="couponDetails sp">

        <div class="owl-carousel mbm">
            <div class="item " ng-repeat="friend in ::coupon.coupon_data.coupon_users">
                <div style="background-image: url('{{::absolute_url}}/images/users/75x75/{{friend.picture}}')" class="roundImages mProfilePics"></div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div   ng-init="coupon.coupon_data.isMapCollapsed =true;coupon.coupon_data.isMapOpened=false">
        <div class="clearfix  bb mbp mtp bt sbm" >
            <div class="pull-left srm"   ng-click="openBranches(coupon.coupon_data)">
                <i class="icon-location"></i>
                <label>{{::'branches'| translate}} {{::coupon.coupon_data.no_of_branches}}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="pull-left">
                <i ng-class="{'icon-cancel':coupon.coupon_data.feed_w_estafeed_id ==null,'icon-ok':coupon.coupon_data.feed_w_estafeed_id != null}"></i>
                <label>{{::'benefit'| translate}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <i class="icon-share"></i>

              <label for="">{{::'share'| translate}} :</label>
                <i class="icon-facebook" ng-click='shareCoupon(coupon.coupon_data.slug,"facebook")'></i>
                <i class="icon-twitter" ng-click='shareCoupon(coupon.coupon_data.slug,"twitter")'></i>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="fc-map " uib-collapse="coupon.coupon_data.isMapCollapsed" >

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">

          <div class="buttons add_to_my_coupones pull-right">
              <button ng-if="coupon.coupon_data.in_wallet  " type="button" class="btn btnr btnp btni" ng-click='couponConditions(coupon.coupon_data.slug)'>{{::'in_my_coupons'| translate}}</button>
              <a ng-if="!coupon.coupon_data.in_wallet && key=='challenges' " href='{{absolute_url}}/{{lang}}/coupons/{{coupon.coupon_data.slug}}/{{coupon.coupon_data.challenges.title}}'  class="btn btnr btnp btni" >ابدء التحدي</a>
              <button ng-if="!coupon.coupon_data.in_wallet && key!='challenges'" analytics-on="click" analytics-event="addToMyCoupons" analytics-properties="{coupon_id:{{coupon.coupon_data.coupon_id}}}" ng-click="addToMyCoupons(coupon.coupon_data)" class="btn btnr btnp btni icon-heart">{{::'add_to_my_coupones'| translate}}</button>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-left">
            <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
            <label class="srm">{{::'available_to' | translate}}</label>
            <!-- <fc-countdown date='coupon.coupon_data.available_to.date'></fc-countdown> -->

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fc-couponComments" >
            <!-- <span>{{coupon.comments.length}} {{::'comments'|translate}}</span> -->
            <button  ng-init="isCollapsed = true;" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;"><i class="icon-comment-1"></i> </button>
            <ul uib-collapse="isCollapsed" >
                <li>
                    <img src="{{ currentUser?absolute_url+'/images/users/50x50/'+currentUser.picture:absolute_url+'/images/user.png'}}"/>
                    <div class="userComment">
                        <textarea ng-model="addComment.newComment" ng-enter="sendComment(coupon)"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li ng-repeat="comment in coupon.coupon_data.comments track by $index">
                    <img ng-src="{{::absolute_url}}/images/users/50x50/{{::comment.user.picture}}"/>
                    <p>
                        <label>{{::comment.user.firstname}} {{::comment.user.lastname}}</label>
                        <span> {{::comment.comment}} </span>
                        <label>{{::comment.created_at}}</label>
                    </p>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

home controller js :

```js
var url = user ? "user/home/coupons" : "home/coupons";

fcDB.query(url, "GET", data).success(function(res) {
    console.log('home', res);
    $scope.coupon_sections = res;
});
```

Comment: Instead of loading the whole data at a time from DB you can limit the records(say for eg 10 records). so once user scrolls the page then you can get the next 10 records, which is like lazy loading. This helps in performance and page loading issues.

Comment: @KethaKavya, Thanks for your reply, I already load 5 sections only and one item for each section and there is a button for load more for each section

Comment: How many coupons per section? Or comments? Where do the `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` come from -how many of those?

Comment: there is only 1 coupon per section, and about 10 comments per coupon, hours,minutes and seconds is a countdown start from the coupon date till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have way too many bindings. Back in the days of Angular 1.2, I remember it was a rule of thumb to have up to 2000 bindings on the page. That's gone up by now, but I doubt it scaled exponentially.

You have 5 sections, each having numerous ng-click bindings, several nested ng-repeats which multiply this, then undetermined number of comments per coupon.

You can deal with all this in several different ways. Some of them:

- join the click listeners,
- lazy-load the nested comments, hours etc, if possible,
- also render as html those social shares,
- pre-translate content,
- one-time-bind more then you do now,
- reduce dependencies.

E.g. you can have one top-level ng-click instead of a dozen per section (+ possibly more in those fc-coupon repeats). So create a single top-level ng-click, and have that function find out its intended target and act accordingly. I'd say you can shave off a little bit of time, but not significant there.

Lazy-load the nested repeats - ie. don't render them immediately. When you initially render the sections, you go on and render those `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`. Dunno why, but it seems like you do really a lot of those. Have those not even show until the main content is rendered. Just one way to do that is to hide the whole block with an ng-if switch and when you know you've loaded and rendered the initial 5 sections, flip one (or all) the switches and wait for those to be rendered too. You can even leave *those* hidden ("Loading comments...") until you know they're rendered with a single css flip. Furthermore, maybe you can do them one-at-a-time. First fully resolve the top section, then the second, then the third etc.

Remember, a lot of performance is in *perceived performance*.

I see you have many of the social shares that you bind to a function. Why not render those as simple HTML directly? Depending on those coupons, you can again remove a lot of bindings.

I see you use ng-translate - which introduces yet more bindings. If you know the user's language in advance, (ie. settings), maybe you can have pre-translated per-language template? E.g. If the user initially chose `english`, he'd load a page called `home-en.html` and `fc-coupon-en.html` instead of one generic one. Don't know if this is viable though, but considering you have a lot of nested content, it might prove useful. And you don't even have to do it by hand, I bet you can write a one-time script where you write your source template like this, and the additional build-step would generate per-language template for all this on build time.

Also try to one-time bind the nested content. E.g. `ng-repeat="hour in ::hours"` might help a bit. Depending on how many times you have to bind hours, minutes and seconds, there may be thousands of bindings to introduce into the page.

Reduce dependencies if you can. E.g. I see you use a "read-more" module. Maybe you can do without it. Just use a css elipsis. And have a second click listener that finds the targeted section and extends/collapses on demand. I bet that's what the original module does anyway, but yours would be one-time top-level click listener, and not a per-item angular binding that has to get sorted out.

Now, these are all guesses, because you don't show how many actual items and what exactly does it do. So take your pick on one of the suggestions, and try it or open up a new question with more details on it.

Personally, I'd think lazy-loading everything will grant you the most "perceived" performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, unfortunately not all your suggestions is applicable but I try the most of your suggestions, Thanks again

Comment: Np, try one step at a time. Removing everything should render the stuff quickly, then add back parts of the template until you see a huge bump. That's the best candidate to look into further.

Comment: I am sorry for not accepting your answer till now, I am waiting to see more suggestions from others as you know the questions with accepted answer doesn't have a good chance for more answers.

Comment: @PeterWilson Yeah, yeah, not a problem. If I was after reputation, I wouldn't go for non-trivial questions like this, I'm posting merely to learn or to help out if I can.